# MySQL Syntax Error In Variable Declaration

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax, variable-declaration

I have the following MySQL query:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertResult (IN winnerID INT, IN loserID INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO KomperResult (WinnerID, LoserID) VALUES (@winnerID, @loserID);
    DECLARE winnerScore, loserScore INT;
    SELECT Score INTO @winnerScore FROM KomperPerson WHERE ID = @winnerID;
    SELECT Score INTO @loserScore FROM KomperPerson WHERE ID = @loserID;
    IF (@loserScore >= @winnerScore) THEN UPDATE KomperPerson SET Score = @loserScore + 1 WHERE ID = @winnerID; END IF;
END//
```

I get an error on:

```
DECLARE winnerScore, loserScore INT;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DECLARE`s need to go on the first line of your procedure.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html):

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a
>   BEGIN ... END compound statement and
>   must be at its start, before any other
>   statements.